# Select Formato yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss em coluna de tabela MYSQL

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, select

Data

```
2014-12-01 10:52:38
2014-12-01 10:52:14
2014-12-01 10:51:57
2014-12-01 10:35:34
2014-12-01 10:23:17
2014-12-01 10:22:18
2014-12-01 09:03:49
2014-12-01 08:53:51
```

Possuo esta coluna com estas datas  e preciso fazer um select que filtre da seguinte forma:
mANDO PARAMETRO DOM aaaaMMDdd com valor já especificado e quero que  a rotina me traga somente as datas de um dia.
A dificuldade é que a coluna esta no formato yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss e o select abaixo nao me traz nada. Como fazer?
Grato

Estou trabalhando com c# winform e MYSQL.
att
Marcos

```
    static public string SelectQuantidadeRenavan(MySqlConnection db, string renavam,string datarecebe)
    {
        string strdata = Convert.ToDateTime(datarecebe).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

        StringBuilder selectQuantidadeRenavam = new StringBuilder();

        selectQuantidadeRenavam.AppendFormat("select count(RENAVAM)");
        selectQuantidadeRenavam.AppendFormat(" from numtermo ");
        selectQuantidadeRenavam.AppendFormat("WHERE ");
        //selectQuantidadeRenavam.AppendFormat("RENAVAM = 1) {0}", renavam);
        selectQuantidadeRenavam.AppendFormat("RENAVAM =  {0} and Data = '{1}'", renavam, strdata) 



        MySqlCommand MysqlResult = new MySqlCommand(selectQuantidadeRenavam.ToString(), db);

        return MysqlResult.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se a coluna no banco admite hora, minutos e segundos, a data gravada lá pode de fato conter estes valores, e você está buscando por uma data sem estes valores. Então no banco poderia estar assim:

```
Data = 2014-01-26 11:22:44
```

E, por não informar o horário, na prática você está procurando por:

```
Data = 2014-01-26 00:00:00
```

Opção:

```
selectQuantidadeRenavam.AppendFormat("RENAVAM =  {0} and Date(Data) = '{1}'", renavam, strdata);
```

No código acima a função **Date** do MySql trunca a data no banco de dados para meia-noite antes de comparar com a sua data, que também está como meia-noite.

#### Algumas observações:

Você está convertendo uma string para data (`Convert.ToDateTime(datarecebe)`) e depois para string novamente (`).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`). Eu entendo que isso é para converter o formato da data para aquele aceito pelo banco, mas parece estranho. Usando desta maneira, certifique-se também de que a data na string `datarecebe` está mesmo vindo no formato da cultura local, ou ao ser convertida para DateTime ela pode resultar em uma data diferente.

O ideal seria você poder receber a data como **DateTime**, daí você a informaria para o SELECT como um parâmetro tipado em vez de concatenar uma string.

Comment: Então Caffé, rodou perfeitamente mas na tabela possui dois RENAVANS iguais e a rotina me retornou somente 1 valor sendo que deveria ser dois.O que pode ter acontecido?

Comment: @JoeliasAndrade Não sei. Sua consulta retornará apenas sempre 1 registro dado que você usou um COUNT. É a quantidade de registros ou o valor do COUNT que não bate? Experimente atualizar sua pergunta com os registros completos (você só informou as datas) e informando também os valores exatos (você pode verificar depurando o aplicativo) recebidos em `renavam` e `datarecebe`.

Comment: Desculpe Caffé mas ontem deu tudo certo sua orientação.Foi eu quem renomeou uma data diferente...Enfim, muito obrigado mesmo.

Comment: Como faço para pontua VC?

Comment: @JoeliasAndrade Você pode clicar no ícone de seta acima ^ do lado esquerdo de uma resposta ou pergunta para votar ou no ícone abaixo das setas, em respostas de perguntas que você fez, para marcar a resposta como resposta aceita. Quando você põe o mouse sobre os ícones aparece a descrição. Veja também: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour